# Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ and $f, g : A \to \Bbb R$, be measurable. Show $\{x \in A : f(x) < g(x) \}$ and $\{x \in A : f(x) = g(x) \}$ are measurable.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ and $f:A \to \Bbb R$, $g: A \to \Bbb R$ be measurable functions. Show that $\{x \in A : f(x) < g(x) \}$ and $\{x \in A : f(x) = g(x) \}$ are measurable sets.

Since both $f$ and $g$ are measurable we can construct $h: = f -g$ which is also measurable. Now $\{x \in A : f(x) < g(x) \} = \{x \in A : h(x) < 0\} = h^{-1}[[-\infty, 0)]$ and $\{x \in A : h(x) = 0 \} = h^{-1}[\{0\}]$

now since $h$ is measruable and the sets $\{0\}$ and $[-\infty, 0)$ since belong to the Borel sigma-algebra the sets $\{x \in A : f(x) < g(x) \}$ and $\{x \in A : f(x) = g(x) \}$ are measurable?

Comment: This is fine if you are allowed to use the fact that linear combinations of measurable functions are measurable. But you can prove it without using that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is perfectly fine. If you want to be really picky, just add why the sets you are picking are Borel.